# How to fill NaN values with the help of pivot table?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

[image] 
  [image]

```
pivot= pd.pivot_table(buliding_area_notnull,values = ['BuildingArea','Landsize'],index=['Bedroom2', 'Bathroom' ,'Car','Type'])
```

this is my code which gives a `pivot table` like=

```
Bedroom2    Bathroom    Car Type    Landsize

1_________1_________1______365.2

__________0_________2_______555[![enter image description here][2]][2]

____________________1________666
```

now i want to fill `NaN` `dataframe['Landsize']` values using above `pivot`.what is the syntax.

note: the above `pivot table` is just a small part.

Comment: What is your expected output from this dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston there is a big dataframe having above attributes. i want Landsize to be filled in NaN places corresponding to the given bedroom,car,bathroom values.

Comment: It would help quite a bit if you could show me a picture of your expected output dataframe.

Comment: @ScottBoston see the screenshot, i want to fill nan values using above pivot table.

Comment: Please look at some other SO pandas questions and see how they give inputs and expected outputs.  This will make your help much easier.  Remember, SO participants are volunteering their time.  Here is a decent example of an easy to follow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45219131/adding-extra-column-as-the-culumative-time-difference/45219617#45219617)

Comment: Also read [MVCE article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: So now I have a better idea of what you are doing.

What you need to do is flatten the multi index of the first dataframe with reset_index().

Then you want to join the two dataframes together on [Bedroom2, Bathroom, Car, Type].

This will give you an 8 column df (the four above plus buildingarea and landsize twice.

Then I would just create a new column and fill with building area from the second df if it is non nan and building area from the first df if it is nan.

EDIT END:

Your output there does not match what the code is that you typed at all.  That being said, there is a fill parameter that you may find useful.

Docs below.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html